# Сохранение данных с формы в файл на сервере

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, jsp

Есть textarea, я его редактирую, затем, нужно сохранить изменения в файл на сервере и вопрос в том, как определить метод WriteToFile(passForm)?
На данный момент реализовано считывание из файла(который на сервере) в textarea и неудачная попытка сохранить изменения.

```js
<jsp:directive.page language="java" pageEncoding="utf-8"/>

<%@ page import="java.io.File" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*" %>

<html>
    <head>
         <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js" runat="both"></script>
  <script>
 function WriteToFile(passForm) {
 
   var data = passForm;
      var url = "/dir/111.txt";
   var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
   http.open("POST", url, true);

   http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
   http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

   http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
            alert(http.responseText);           
   }
   }
   http.send(data);  
}
</script>

    </head>
    <body>
 <div>
 <form onSubmit="WriteToFile(this)">
  <textarea class="content" style="width:70%" id=textarea name="Text1" rows="100">
   <%
   File file = new File("1.txt");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
   while (sc.hasNextLine()){
          out.println(sc.nextLine());   
   }
   %>
  </textarea>
 <input type="submit" value="submit">  
 </form>
  </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Как-то надо сообщить сервлету, что вы сохраняете файл.

Comment: К какому файлу? у вас нет файла тут. Вы выводите содержимое файла `1.txt`. Сам файл можно выбрать при помощи стандартных средств в браузере и элемента `<input type="file" />`.

Comment: @Tsyklop изменения нужно сохранить в том же файле, с которого я считываю.

Comment: @Alex тогда вам нужно делать `AJAX` запрос на сервер с новыми данными. ну и сервер будет обновлять файл. Поймите что веб интерфейс и знать не знает а ваших файлах и т.д.

Comment: @Tsyklop в `function WriteToFile(passForm)` можно таким образом url задать?  я не понимаю как указать, что именно этот файл мне н7ужно обновить

Comment: @Alex это делает сервер, а не html. Делаете `http` запрос на Ваш сервер и сохраняете файл.